# Comparing value in the datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I am trying to work on a datatable to compare new value with the existing datatable, if available, quantity will add up but if not, it will add a row in the datatable.

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"] != null)
{
    DataTable shoppingcart = (DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"];
    for (int i = 0; i < shoppingcart.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        String checktitle = shoppingcart.Rows[i]["Title"].ToString();
            if (title == checktitle)
            {
                //do something
            }
            else
            {

                ShoppingCart.DataSource = cart.cartrow(shoppingcart);
                ShoppingCart.DataBind();
            }
        }

    }

    else
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"] = cart.shoppingCart();
        ShoppingCart.DataSource = cart.shoppingCart();
        ShoppingCart.DataBind();
    }

}
```

but somehow. I couldn't manage to add its quantity. it was creating a new row everytime. 
Thanks for the advice. 
This is the class that i was using to add row or add table

```
String title { get; set; }
decimal price { get; set; }
int quantity { get; set; }
DataTable CartTable;
DataRow tableRow;
public cart(String _title, decimal _price)
{
    title = _title;
    price = _price;
}
public DataTable shoppingCart()
{
    CartTable = new DataTable("cart");

    CartTable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(Int32));
    CartTable.Columns["ID"].AutoIncrement = true;
    CartTable.Columns["ID"].AutoIncrementSeed = 1;

    CartTable.Columns.Add("Title");
    CartTable.Columns.Add("Price");
    CartTable.Columns.Add("quantity");


    tableRow = CartTable.NewRow();
    tableRow["Title"] = title;
    tableRow["Price"] = price;
    tableRow["quantity"] = quantity;
    CartTable.Rows.Add(tableRow);
    return CartTable;
}

public DataTable cartrow(DataTable _cart)
{

    tableRow = _cart.NewRow();
    tableRow["Title"] = title;
    tableRow["Price"] = price;
    tableRow["quantity"] = quantity;
    _cart.Rows.Add(tableRow);
    return _cart;

}
```

Comment: Your code does not show what you're asking. Where do you compare that value, add a quantity and create a new row?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a novice in programming. I created a class to run my adding of rows and table

Answer (score 0):

you run this code:

```
ShoppingCart.DataSource = cart.cartrow(shoppingcart);
ShoppingCart.DataBind();
```

each time your condition is false: title == checktitle

I'm not sure this is the error, but you should build something different, like this:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"] != null)
{
    DataTable shoppingcart = (DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"];
    //put here each row you need to bind
    DataTable toBind = new DataTable();  //do more to init the columns, rows, etc

    for (int i = 0; i < shoppingcart.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        String checktitle = shoppingcart.Rows[i]["Title"].ToString();
            if (title == checktitle)
            {
                //do something
            }
            else
            {
                toBind.add(cart.cartrow(shoppingcart));  //the sintax here is incorect, I code directly here
                //ShoppingCart.DataSource = cart.cartrow(shoppingcart);
                //ShoppingCart.DataBind();
            }
        }
        //bind outside the for cicle
        ShoppingCart.DataSource = toBind ;
        ShoppingCart.DataBind();
    }

    else
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"] = cart.shoppingCart();
        ShoppingCart.DataSource = cart.shoppingCart();
        ShoppingCart.DataBind();
    }

}
```

I hope this give you a direction to correct your code. I coded this directly  into the browser, and I don't remember the exact syntax to init a DataTable or to add a row to it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use foreach:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"] != null)
{
    DataTable shoppingcart = (DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"];

    foreach (DataRow row in shoppingcart.Rows)
    {
            String checktitle = row["Title"].ToString();
            int price = row["price"].ToString();
            int quantity = row["quantity"].ToString();

            if (title == checktitle)
            {
                //do something
            }
            else
            {

                Session["Cart"] = cart.cartrow(shoppingcart,checktitle,price,quantity);
                ShoppingCart.DataSource = Session["Cart"]  as DataTable();
                ShoppingCart.DataBind();
            }
     }

 }
```

Your CartRow

```
public DataTable cartrow(DataTable _cart,string title,int price,int quantity)
{

    tableRow = _cart.NewRow();
    tableRow["Title"] = title;
    tableRow["Price"] = price;
    tableRow["quantity"] = quantity;
    _cart.Rows.Add(tableRow);
    return _cart;

}
```

Comment: Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute.